# R / tidyverse - find intersect between multiple character columns

Tags: r, string, set, tidyverse

I have the following problem, I have a `tibble` with mutliple character columns.
I tried to provide an MRE below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(food = c("pizza, bread, apple","joghurt, cereal, banana"), 
             food2 = c("bread, sausage, strawberry", "joghurt, oat, bacon"),
             food3 = c("ice cream, bread, milkshake", "melon, cake, joghurt")
             )
df %>%
  # rowwise() %>%
  mutate(allcolumns = map2(
    str_split(food, ", "),
    str_split(food2, ", "),
    # str_split(food3, ", "),
    intersect
  ) %>% unlist()
  ) -> df_new
```

My goal would be to get the common words for ***all*** columns. Words are separated by `,` in the columns. In the MRE I am able to find the intersect between two columns, however I couldnt get a solution for this issue. I experimented with `Reduce` but was not able to get it.

As an EDIT: I would also like to append it as a new row to the existing tibble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `map` to loop over the columns, do the `str_split` and then `reduce` to get the `intersect` for elementwise `intersect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   purrr::map(str_split, ", ") %>%
   transpose %>%
   purrr::map_chr(reduce, intersect) %>%
   mutate(df, Intersect = .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  food                    food2                      food3                       Intersect
  <chr>                   <chr>                      <chr>                       <chr>    
1 pizza, bread, apple     bread, sausage, strawberry ice cream, bread, milkshake bread    
2 joghurt, cereal, banana joghurt, oat, bacon        melon, cake, joghurt        joghurt
```

---

or may also use `pmap`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Intersect = pmap(across(everything(), str_split, ", "), 
        ~ list(...) %>%
              reduce(intersect)))
```

Comment: This does work to create a list, ofc. we can do pipe into unlist and assign it as a new column, e.g. `df$allcolumns <- df %>% 
  purrr::map(str_split, ", ") %>%
  transpose %>%
  purrr::map(reduce, intersect) %>% 
  unlist()` is that the proper way to do so? I updated the goal, which is a new column with the intersect

Comment: @SysRIP updated the post.  Here, i used `map_chr` as there is only a single intersect.  If there are multiple intersects, you may need a `list` i.e. it should be a list column, therefore change the `map_chr` to just `map` (updatd tehe post)

Comment: @SysRIP I wouldn't use `unlist` based on the previous comment i.e. if one row is returning two elements and next only one, it creates imbalance

Comment: Thanks! I just realized you import several tidyverse libraries, is there a specific reasoning for not just loading tidyverse?

Comment: @SysRIP the main reason is that `tidyverse` loads more libraries than is needed.  here, I need only 3 and if tidyverse loads all and some packages have same function names as others, it may mask the function of the one which we need and thus code could break unless we use `::`

Comment: Ok thank you for the elaboration. I really enjoy `conflicted` from hadley wickham for this issue. But in general it is probably advisable to only load libs that you really need

Comment: @SysRIP The commonly found issue is with `summarise/mutate` mask from plyr wrt to dplyr leading to incorrect output